# Batch convert ISO/WAV/CUE back into BIN/CUE

Tags: command-line, iso, format-conversion

I've been looking for a command utility/script that does the opposite of bchunck, but can't seem to find one.

What bchunck does is taking a mixed-mode CD image in BIN/CUE format and separate it into a set of ISO and music tracks (either CDR or WAV). I want to use a tool to reverse the process.

I can do this with a Windows utility like CDmage under WINE, or following [this guide](https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/Convert-iso-track-wav-bin-to-bin-cue-(EN)) (also dependent on WINE or Windows), but I'd love a way to automate the process and use it natively on Linux.

---

Here's what I tried so far. Let's say I have a Mixed-mode CD test image with 1 data track and 4 music tracks, IMAGE.bin and IMAGE.cue, generated from a physical CD:

```
cdrdao read-cd --datafile IMAGE.bin --driver generic-mmc:0x20000 --device /dev/cdrom --read-raw IMAGE.toc
toc2cue IMAGE.toc IMAGE.cue
```

If I do `bchunk -v -w IMAGE.bin IMAGE.cue track` it outputs the following files:

track01.iso

track02.wav

track03.wav

track04.wav

track05.wav

Now to try to put the image back together:

First I convert track01.iso back to the BIN format using the [PowerISO Linux tool](https://www.poweriso.com/download.php) with `./poweriso convert track01.iso -o IMAGE-NEW.bin -ot bin`. Note that a IMAGE-NEW.cue is generated, but it doesn't contain any music track information, so it should be discarded, and the original IMAGE.cue be used instead.

Secondly, I convert the WAV files back to RAW and concatenate them to IMAGE-NEW.bin:

```
avconv -i trackC02.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
avconv -i trackC03.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
avconv -i trackC04.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
avconv -i trackC05.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
```

IMAGE-NEW.bin, together with the original IMAGE.cue seem to be working fine as a Mixed-mode CD image. However, if I do `diff IMAGE.bin IMAGE-new.bin` it outputs that they are different, so I'm not sure if this method I came up with is the correct one, or if this is a consequence of both images being generated using different methods.

That said, if I do `bchunk -v -w IMAGE-NEW.bin IMAGE.cue track-new` and diff all `track` and `track-new` files to each other, they are indeed identical. I don't have enough experience with comparing binaries to know if I'm doing this right and why IMAGE.bin IMAGE-new.bin are different.

---

UPDATE: I now understand what the problem is: bchunk doesn't splice my IMAGE.bin properly because my IMAGE.cue has multiple INDEX entries per TRACK. When bchunk does the splicing it only takes into account the last INDEX entry of each TRACK. Otherwise, this method is the correct one to try to rebuild an IMAGE.bin that was previously ripped. If you used bchunk before and lost the original IMAGE.bin, there's a good change you won't be able to rebuild it, since you may have lost information. If you used, for example, asunder to rip the audio tracks, they are spliced correctly and you'll be able to rebuild IMAGE.bin, as long as you used a lossless format to store the audio tracks.

Comment: The .bin file format is a raw sector-by-sector copy of a disk, so perhaps you could mount the .iso using the loop-back device and use dd to create a binary image. You would have to create the .cue file manually. Take a look at this  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_(computing)) article.

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I've managed to do so far.

Comment: This question might get an answer on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), people there know about stuff like that.

Comment: What are you actually attempting to accomplish here? if you are expecting an end result of exactly cloning the disk there are far more effective ways. since simply using bchunk is converting the CD Audio tracks to .WAV files you will never end up with a bit for bit identical copy no matter what you do after that.

Comment: Reversing what bchunck did and get back to BIN/CUE means I can use the image again with certain programs and emulators, and sadly, I have a couple of images in ISO/WAV/CUE whose CDs no longer work properly, so I can't actually regenerate the BIN/CUE images from scratch.

That's why I came up with this method that seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's technically correct.

Comment: maybe the original `IMAGE.cue` file had pregap/postgap? sometimes you can also find AUDIO tracks with `INDEX 00 mm:ss:ff` and `INDEX 01 mm:ss:ff` with a 2 sec difference between the two. The question is how does bchunk handle the gaps? maybe when you convert WAVs back to RAWs and append to `IMAGE-NEW.bin` you need to account for the gaps?

Comment: you can find more explanation with examples of gaps here: http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Cue_sheet